# Strncpy issue with Double Pointer Char Array

Tags: c, strcpy, pointer-arithmetic, double-pointer

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code below:

I have a double pointer `char` array, declared and initialized with the following:

```
unsigned char **buffer = (unsigned char**) malloc (num * sizeof(char*));
for ( i = 0; i < num; i++ )
{
    buffer[i] = (unsigned char*) calloc(PACKETSIZE, sizeof(char));
}
```

Then I'm trying to copy a string to the middle section of one of the `char*` arrays, but it does not seem to work.  I'm not sure whether my error was with the memory allocation or when I tried to copy.  I know for a fact the source `char*` has content.

The code I'm trying to copy (Header is a struct, I want to write to the array after the memory address of Header for `buffer[i]`, so I'm doing a bit of a pointer arithmetic).

```
 strncpy ((unsigned char *)(buffer[i]+sizeof(Header)), buffer2, bytes_to_copy);
```

After the code runs, the `buffer[i]` stays empty.

Here is a sample of the Header struct:

```
typedef struct Head
{
    unsigned int x; 
    unsigned int y; 
} Header ;
```

Comment: General hint: `strncpy` is not the somewhat safer version of `strcpy`. Read the documentation closely.

Comment: So what's the relation between PACKETSIZE and `sizeof(Header)`? This smells like a plain out of bounds access. Do these things in several steps, store `buffer[i]+sizeof(Header)` in a tmp variable and watch it in your debugger. Does it make sense? Also, always suspect the dangerous `strncpy` function, does it actually null terminate the string in this case? Use the safer `strcpy` or `memcpy` instead, if possible.

Comment: Also... if you calloc `buffer[i]` it's all zeroes. If you then write to `buffer[i] + whatever`, then `buffer[i]` will still contain zero. So what do you mean "empty"? There is a null terminator in the beginning of the string `buffer[i]`, as per your program design.

Comment: So my issue seems to be a combination of both you and Adrian's answer below.  For my strncpy, i initially forgot to add the Null char to terminate my buffer.  However, after I fixed it, using strcpy, My debugger statements were still not outputting anything when i thought it was still not working, but this was due to my header having small unsigned int values, which, when having 0s in a byte, act like a null char for my debug statement so the packet appeared empty but it was really not.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: really appreciate everyone's help!  Been stuck on this for the whole night.

Answer (score 1):

Your allocation line:

```c
    buffer[i] = (unsigned char*) calloc(PACKETSIZE, sizeof(char));
```

will set *all* elements of `buffer[i]` to zero.

Then, your copy line:

```c
    strncpy ((unsigned char *)(buffer[i]+sizeof(Header)), buffer2, bytes_to_copy);
```

will *only* set the `buffer[i]` data that come *after* the first `sizeof(Header)` elements.

So, those first `sizeof(Header)` elements will be zero. Thus, any attempt to use a `strxxx` function to display that buffer will assume the string is empty (first byte is zero).

Comment: Actually sorry i forgot to mention I did set values to the header already.

Comment: @TimZ But what did you set them *to*? Chances are, if the first `int` of the header structure is something like `7`, then the first *byte* of that will *still* be zero. If you want to use character-string functions to count or print the data, you need to pass `buffer[i]+sizeof(header)` to *each of those functions*.

Comment: that's true!! i think that's why my debugger (printf) isn't working since i'm trying to print %s.  is there a way for me to print the whole char array for the entire length that was allocated regardless of 0s?

Comment: @TimZ My suggestion is to not use string storage for data that is not string data. Maybe make a `struct` that has your header's `x` and `y` elements *plus* a `char*` data pointer?

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible :( i'm trying to send the packet through a socket call.  But anyways, i think my issue is resolved, thanks!  ALso I figured out to output the correct data section of the string, i can just use pointer arithmetic again.